# unknown syntaxerror cause when declaring list on PyQt

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pyqt4

i had this weird syntax error at the end of my newly declared list that contains only string.

i had changed the double quotation mark (") into single ('). commented 2 lines above the data variable

i also check for tabs and spaces.

i'm running this on spyder

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("cleanlooks")

    #DATA
    data = ["one","two","three","four","five"]

    listView = QtGui.QListView()    
    listView.show()

    model = QtGui.QStringListModel(data)

    listView.setModel(model)


    combobox = QtGui.QComboBox()
    combobox.setModel(model)
    combobox.show()

    listView2 = QtGui.QListView()
    listView2.show()
    listView2.setModel(model)


    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> runfile('C:/Users/abdull/.spyder/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/abdull/.spyder')
>     File "C:/Users/abdull/.spyder/temp.py", line 10
>       data = ["one","two","three","four","five"]
>                                                 ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The code from your OP looks okay and has no syntax errors. Can you try to copy/paste it back from here and run?

Comment: it gave me exact same error

Comment: What's your Python version? (python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)")

Comment: okay this is weird. somehow it works by closing the spyder IDE and open it back up again. mine is python 2.7 . thank you by the way for your help